# Stuck at boot screen during installation

Tags: system-installation

I want dual boot KUbuntu with windows 10.
Steps I followed :
1. Flashed kubuntu 18.04 image using rufus as shown in ubuntu's installation guide.

2. Turned off fast startup and secure boot.
3. Boot from usb.

When I boot from Usb I get only kubuntu loading screen and nothing else after that. No install or try option. Just stuck at the start of boot. Only. Kubuntu logo glows once and then gets stuck.

I used that image on virtual box and its running fine.

I've heard that it has issues with nvidia drivers. I'm having gtx 1050.
Please help I'm a newbie to linux.

Even in ubuntu I am getting same error.

Comment: I faced the same problem. I have tried in Rufus with different usbs. All I see is getting stuck at Ubuntu logo with 3 dots. Later I started Rufus in other system and made the bootable USB and kept this USB in the system I wanted to install Ubuntu. It worked.

Comment: Thanks friend I tried but it didn't work. I also tried universal usb installer.  It also didn't work. But by following the universal usb process I am able to get a menu before installation but again when I choose to install kubuntu I face same issue. @PRATAP

Comment: Have you tried to make the USB bootable from other System with RUFUS?

Comment: Yes but its still not working. @PRATAP